# sending html email using php / outlook not displaying html properly

Tags: php, html, email, outlook

i am using php to send a html email like so in my send_email.php file:

```
 <?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'mark.obrien2014@inbox.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Hewden New Supplier Setup';

// message
$message = file_get_contents('../../assets/email/email.php');

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mark <mark.obrien2014@inbox.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Hewden New Supplier Setup <NewSuppliers@hewden.co.uk>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: purchasing@hewden.co.uk' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

I am including my email html in a seperate file email.php using

```
 $message = file_get_contents('../../assets/email/email.php');
```

I am testing my email has been sent using Outlook 2010 on windows and also testing it in a normal webmail. The email sends fine on both but in outlook the html doesn't seem to display properly. My email looks fine in every other email program and all other webmail. can someone please show me what i am doing wrong? thanks in advance

my email html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body leftpadding="0" offset="0" paddingheight="0" paddingwidth="0" toppadding="0" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; background:#F6F6F6; width: 100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table align="center" class='bgBody' border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; background:#fff; border:1px solid #999; margin-top:50px;" width="750">
                <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <img src="http://hewdenportal.co.uk/assets/email/images/bigImg.png" width="750" height="258" />
        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    </tr>
</table>

        <table align="center" class='bgBody' border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:100; font-size:16px; background:#000; color:#4f4f4f; border:1px solid #999; margin-top:20px;" width="752">
                <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <div class="container" style="min-height:200px; width:690; background:#fff; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px; font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:100; font-size:15px;">
                <div class="text" style="width:72%;">
                <h1 style="font-family:helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:100; font-size:20px;">Getting Started</h1>
                <p>Thanks for taking an Interest in joining Hewden as an approved supplier.<br/>We care about providing a good quality to service to Customer's and Supplier's alike.</p>
                <p>As part of the Hewden journey blah blah blah.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="find_more" style="width:110px; border:1px solid #666; height:20px; background:rgba(255,195,82,1); margin-top:10px; float:right; position:relative; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; text-align:center; padding:6px;">Find out More ></div>
            </div>
        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

email in webmail showing correct html:

[image: email showing correct html]

email in outlook with distorted html:

[image: email in outlook]

Answer (score 0):

Using `div` in html emails is a little tricky and if you can get away with `table` that'd be easier in general. I would guess the specific issue here is that Outlook 2010 doesn't support `width`, `position`, or `float` for `div`. Campaign Monitor wrote a nice roundup of `div` compatibility [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2011/05/div-tags-in-html-email-newsletters/).

Comment: @Whosoever downvoted the answer : It being the only answer, and seeming to point out a possible reason for the problem asker is having, just to know, any comment on why downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

Use  or `<button>` tags instead of a `<div>` tag.
As far as I know (I send HTML emails pretty often), buttons are well more accepted on Outlook and other email providers.
HTML emails are very annoying sometimes... :)